# Formula with obviously correct syntax still returns an input error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm totally stuck - the below array formula copied from the respected source:

```
=SUM(LARGE(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT(“1:10”))))
```

produces an error during the input:

```
The formula you typed contains an error.
```

Sure thing I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
Obviously that should be something too simple to notice. TOO simple for me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but as soon as you copied the formula from somewhere (perhaps web or PDF or whatever) - **check the quotes**!

Many times I got stuck with exactly the same: double quotes with codes 147 & 148 look way too similar to "plain" ones, i.e. `CHAR(34)` which are generated  in Excel while typing. However, only the last ones are acceptable for using in formulas. So..... check these first! ;)

Comment: Yup, I copied the formula from the question and got the same error. Changed the quotes and everything works as expected.